# Code for calculating jobs remaining for Chef

Tags: c++, arrays, segmentation-fault, gdb, runtime-error

Recently while practicing in codechef I came across [this](https://www.codechef.com/problems/CLEANUP) problem.

Everything went fine , it was an easy problem , simple logic , well it took no more than 10 mins to cook the code and it also ran fine in my machine but giving a `Runtime Error(SIGSEGV)` when I try to execute it in codechef.

I thought there might some problem with the arrays I have used , no help, i tried to debug it with `gdb` it also shows well , i even tried big test cases like about 1000 or so , it ran fine , then why its showing a runtime error in codechef?

Here is the Code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int testCases;
    std::cin >> testCases;
    while(testCases--)
    {
        int jobs,n;
        std::cin >> jobs >> n;
        int doneJobs[n];
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            std::cin >> doneJobs[i];
        }
        bool todoJobs[jobs] = {false};
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            todoJobs[doneJobs[i] - 1] = true;
        }
        bool toSkip = false;
        for(int i = 0; i < jobs; i++)
        {
            if(todoJobs[i] == false)
            {
                if(toSkip == false)
                {
                    std::cout << i + 1 << ' ';
                    toSkip = true;
                    todoJobs[i] = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    toSkip = false;
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for(int i = 0; i < jobs; i++)
        {
            if(todoJobs[i] == false)
            {
                std::cout << i+1 << ' ';
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**Edit** :
Thanks to  @DominiqueLorre for pointing out that some random values entered can result in an `Runtime Error` , but still I am getting it here is my edited code:

```
#include <iostream>

int main(){
    int testCases;
    std::cin >> testCases;
    while(testCases--){
        int jobs,n;
        std::cin>>jobs>>n;
        bool todoJobs[jobs] = {false};
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            int testJob;
            std::cin >> testJob;
            todoJobs[testJob-1] = true;
            }
        bool toSkip = false;
        for(int i=0;i<jobs;i++){
            if(todoJobs[i] == false){
                if(toSkip == false){
                    std::cout << i+1 << ' ';
                    toSkip = true;
                    todoJobs[i] = true;
                }else{
                    toSkip = false;
                }
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
        for(int i=0;i<jobs;i++){
            if(todoJobs[i] == false){
                std::cout << i+1 << ' ';
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I've got a seg-fault with this input (first try): 3
2
1
1
(2 <- displayed)

1
2
23
2

Comment: can you explain the test case? @DominiqueLorre

Comment: I've just input random values, you need to implement error checking. Your program is crashing at this line:             todoJobs[doneJobs[i]-1] = true;

Comment: ahh i never though codechef would do that

Comment: well still I am getting a runtime error

Comment: Your code will error if  both `jobs` and `n` is 0. C++14 does not allow zero-sized dynamic array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to problem definition, it's stated that `n,m satisfying 0 ≤ m ≤ n ≤ 1000` (in your code `n => jobs, m => n`), thus test case `0 0` is valid. However, the following snippet will causing runtime error if `jobs` is 0, since C++14 does not allow declaration of zero-sized dynamic array.

```
bool todoJobs[jobs] = {false};
```

Add statement to check the value of `jobs` before array allocation.

```
if (jobs <= 0) continue;
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight